# selecting only one div among class via .this not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I have two vimeo videos and a title that fades in when the play button is pressed…
It works perfect for one video, but if I add more with the same class it breaks…
I tried using .this to select only one but somehow it doesn't work…

Here's the fiddle with one video…

https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/8/

And here's the fiddle with two videos…

https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/15/

this is the query code:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.on('play', function() {
    $(".text").fadeIn( "slow" );
});

 player.on('pause', function() {
   $(".text").fadeOut( "slow" );
});

$( "html" ).click(function() {
$( ".text" ).fadeOut("slow")
});
```

this the html:

```
<div class="video" id="item_1">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155851922?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320" height="320"     frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>        </iframe></div>
<div class="text">Text_1</div>
<div class="video" id="item_2">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155851922?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320" height="320"    frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>    </iframe></div>
<div class="text">Text_2</div>
```

I want that if the play button from #item_1 is pressed Text_1 is shown
and if #item_2 is pressed Text_2 is shown…

How do I need to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/21/

```
$.each($('.video'), function(index, element){
        var iframe = $(this).find("iframe");
        var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    player.on('play', function() {
            console.log($(this.element).parent().attr('id'));
        $(this.element).parent().children('.text').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    player.on('pause', function() {
       $(this.element).parent().children('.text').fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

you have to iterate through the video objects and set their click handlers individually

Comment: does it not work because you cannot next your elements or is it the function?

Comment: I only can let the div fadeIn via…

    player.on('play', function() {
        $(".text").fadeIn( "slow" );
    });

Comment: I guess I'm confused, did you next `.text` within the `.video` div? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Yes, but clicking the .video does not work… because of the iframe…
See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/18/

here is a fiddle where it works with only one:
https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/8/

Answer (score 1):

Nest the text within the video elements and do the following:

```
player.on('play', function() {
    $(this.element).next('.text').fadeIn( "slow" );
});

 player.on('pause', function() {
   $(this.element).next('.text').fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/19/

`$(this)` doesnt work for vimeo player because, the player sets its own this object context. Hence if you inspect the player's this you can see that it has an 'element' attribute which represents the current element clicked. So you need to use `$(this.element)` instead of `$(this)`.

To solve the multiple video issue, see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/27/

Comment: It works, but only for the first video… not for the second – I am confused…

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/19/

Comment: That's because your player variable is only for the first iframe I believe, you may need multiple player elements for each of those vimeo players.

Comment: You mean like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/4h1xfmrk/22/

That works! So i have to add code each time i load up a new video?

Comment: Yes but you can put that in a function and call it in a loop.

Comment: No probs, separating it out into a function is good practice. :). Modular programming. Plus you can reuse it.